# git-svn: Is there a good branching and merging pattern?

Tags: git, svn, merge, git-svn, branching-and-merging

I'm running the git-svn client on my machine.  I'd like to have a pattern similar to a standard git branching and merging pattern, wherein you have a development branch which was branched from trunk, and you have several feature or bug-fix branches that have extended from the development branch.

The problem I'm having is that I can't figure out how to make that all work with git-svn.  I know that merging is a pain with vanilla subversion and that it's nice with vanilla git, but it's also turning out to be a pain with git-svn.

So.... what is the best practice?  How can you branch and merge confidently and easily with git-svn?  What is the development practices with it?

I would like to follow this pattern:

```
* Master
|\
| * Development
| |\
| | * Feature
| | |
| | * a commit to feature
| |\|
| | * merge Development into Feature
| | |
| |/|
| * | merge Feature into Development
 ... etc
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!!

**EDIT**

Just to clarify - each git branch should correspond with an svn branch.  This is a team workflow, where team members should be able to work on feature and bug fix branches.

Comment: http://www.google.it/imgres?imgurl=http://jacovanstaden.files.wordpress.com/2011/03/git-flow-overview.jpg&imgrefurl=http://yakiloo.com/getting-started-git-flow/&h=956&w=1470&sz=103&tbnid=_sNW9IzhcShU_M:&tbnh=90&tbnw=138&zoom=1&usg=__04NLpmI4raoHkFBm8S3gc4ogLhg=&docid=dzRqqf-5b1CMdM&sa=X&ei=2feGUtXDCtDG7AaCyYDQDw&ved=0CE8Q9QEwAg

Comment: @sensonario, no SVN mentioned there

Comment: As long as your work branch are purely in your local git repo, I don't see a problem. Create work branch, work, merge to master, dcommit back to svn. That's a pattern I use regularly.

Comment: It's not, the git branches correspond to actual svn branches.  This is a team workflow

Answer (score 1):

In short:

- branch server side
- synchronize merge single direction (from trunk to branches/feature)
- merge back (reintegrate) once for all (this will close the branch)

This my current recommended workflow with svn based on some notes.
Words in between < and > are place holders.

**Tips:**

T1: use the symbols "^/" to refer to your base repository.
From anywhere in your project you can list against the repository with:

```
svn list ^/<repo_path>
```

T2: to now on which branch you are currently working use

```
svn info | grep URL
```

**Recommendations:**

R1: do not checkout the top project dir (the one containing trunk/ branches/ and tag/) but the trunk dir itself, i.e.:

don't do:

```
svn checkout <BASE_URL>/svn/<proj>
```

but do:

```
svn checkout <BASE_URL>/svn/<proj>/trunk workdir
```

and use switch.

R2- When branching, always do it server side to avoid copying.

dont'do:

```
svn cp workdir/trunk workdir/branches/feature
```

do:

```
svn cp ^/trunk ^/branches/feature
```

followed by:

```
cd <workdir_path>
svn sw ^/branches/feature
```

R3: only merge (synchronize) from trunk to your branch.

```
cd <workdir_path>
svn merge ^/trunk
```

R4: to merge on the other direction (from branch to trunk) use reintegrate merge.

```
svn up
svn switch ^/trunk
svn merge --reintegrate ^/branches/<feature>
(resolve conflicts and ...)
svn ci
```

Exception: If you need to cherry-pick a change to the trunk, you may preffer to do it with the --ignore-ancestry (to avoid complication with history)